# how sort file with tab delimiter

Tags: shell

Now I generate one text file,band the values are stored as \t
value1  value2  valu3.

And I want to sort this text file as the value1

```
sort a.txt -o a.txt1
```

And found it happen wrong

```
google 1 1
google 1 2
google 1 3
=google 1 4
google 1 3
```

found =google was inserted between google.Why it happened,so stranged.

And I tried `sort a.txt -t $'\t' -k 1 -o a.txt1` but it has the same issue.

Comment: It is not clear what your input is and what is the use of the $'\t'

Comment: @Himanshu: `$'\t'` is one way to specify a tab in Bash.  See e.g. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings

Comment: Thanks @tripleee and I thought I knew lots of bash :)

Answer (score 3):

Your locale apparently specifies that `=` should be ignored when sorting. Try to replace `sort` with `LC_ALL=C sort`. This will run `sort` with the environment variable `LC_ALL` temporarily set to `C`, which will override your locale (in any locale-aware program) to the "traditional" / legacy locale-ignorant "C" locale.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sort -n x.txt
google 1 1
google 1 2
google 1 3
google 1 3
=google 1 4
```